# Default zoom issue in Google Maps place mode

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using [Google Maps Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide) with place mode in an `iframe`. I am passing the `zoom` parameter but it's not working. However, when I click on "View larger map" the zoom level is used.

The embedded URL is

https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=AIzaSyAb9V7hKU334BfV4yLIOhcQyUu1ERkU_ZQ&q=44215+15th+St+W+Lancaster,CA+93534&center=34.4503429,-117.923845&zoom=17

```
<html>
  <body>
    <iframe
      width="450"
      height="250"
      frameborder="0" style="border:0"
      src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=AIzaSyAb9V7hKU334BfV4yLIOhcQyUu1ERkU_ZQ&q=44215+15th+St+W+Lancaster,CA+93534&center=34.4503429,-117.923845&zoom=17">
    </iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `The Google Maps Embed API must be used in an iframe.`

Comment: yes it is used in iframe

Comment: @owt Is this still a problem? When using your HTML above I'm seeing a reasonable map that is correctly centered (as opposed to centered at a query result) and zoomed (as opposed to default `zoom=15`). I'm just wondering because with the current situation it seems you had a problem with centering, not zooming in the first place. Also, from fiddling with the API it seems to me `zoom` can only be used with either an explicit `center` parameter or a center implicitly given by a search result that is a thing (e.g. place of business, landmark) or address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be the `center` parameter that's causing this (although I'm unsure why as according to the [Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide) the center parameter is supported by all 4 map modes

I changed the URL to https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=AIzaSyAb9V7hKU334BfV4yLIOhcQyUu1ERkU_ZQ&q=44215+15th+St+W+Lancaster,CA+93534&zoom=17 and it seems to work